# Voltage Regulator: MCP1700-3302E (TO-92) current output too low compared to datasheet circuit

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, datasheet, lipo

I'm currently using a pack of MCP1700-3302Es that I purchased online that I plan to use for a project. The project intends to use a 3.7V Lithium Polymer battery; I'm currently testing with an input voltage of 3.7V - 4.2V. However, when I measure the current from a 18 Ohm resistor, I'm getting a current output of 125mA with voltage output of 3.0V (3.7V voltage input), and 132mA with voltage output of 3.3V (4.2V voltage input). The decoupling I'm using is 1uF aluminum electrolytic capacitors; the "description" section states that it can replace ceramic.

My question is how can I get around 200mA output as mentioned in the datasheet? I can't even get to 150mA with the provided schematic. Could it be a bad batch as well?

[image: MCP-1700 Voltage Output with 3.7V Voltage Input]
[image: MCP-1700 Voltage Output with 4.2 Voltage Input]
[image: Breadboard]
[image: MCP1700 Datasheet Example]

Comment: How are you putting 3.55v across 18 ohms (197mA by Ohms law) and getting 132mA?  Are you sure you're measuring correctly?

Comment: Supplying the MCP1700 with 3.7V, I'm breaking the circuit and placing the ammeter from the end of the resistor, to the top of the yellowish lead on the right side of the picture. I got roughly 128mA.

Comment: Where did the 3.55v come from? That's a 3.3v regulator. Does it regulate correctly for a smaller load?

Comment: I'll edited the question. The negative channel (to ground) of the oscilloscope may've fell out during measurement. Now, when measure the current from the resistor to the yellow lead, the output voltage drops from 3.3 to 3.0V, but my output current is still roughly 130mA.

Comment: Without the ammeter, the output voltage from the regulator is now a very close 3.3V. But, the output current is still 125mA - 130mA.

Comment: There might be a few things at play here. Firstly those ‘dupont wires’ can be thin as, thus expect some voltage drop. When you’ve only got a few tenths of a volt margin, this can be significant. Also note using your multimeter to measure current can cause voltage drop due to its sense resistor. Determine current by measuring your load resistor  and the voltage across it. Also measure the voltage drop across your wires. The results might be surprising.

Comment: @Kartman, I measured the voltage across the load resistor. I got 2.78V. 2.78/18 = 155mA. Is that what the datasheet meant? When across a load resistor? When I break the load resistor and the wire, I get 130mA. And what your saying is that these types of wires, combined throughout the circuit can increase the voltage drop to get the 130mA? Across two wires, I got 1.5mV.

Comment: What was the input voltage to the regulator? This should be measured at the regulator’s pins. Now you’re getting 155mA - this suggests the measurement technique and voltage drops were giving strange results.

Comment: If the regulator is outputting 3.3v, then it's working correctly. Try measuring each voltage drop from the battery to the load and then calculating current from voltage.

Comment: Thank you both for you input so far! When I measure at the regulator pins, I get my input voltage of 3.7 and my output voltage of 3.3V. But I'm still lost when I measure the voltage across the load resistor, I'm getting 2.7V.

Comment: You have 3.3-2.7=0.6v dropped in between the two points you measured, probably due to the sum of the wire, contact and breadboard resistance. You can measure to confirm that with your voltmeter.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any suggestions on how to decrease my voltage drop (choice of wires, breadboards)? Would creating a PCB also resolve this issue?

Comment: Would a larger capacitor also work to temporarily increase the voltage across the load resistor?

Comment: I removed some of the wires and I'm now getting 3.18V across the resistor. It looks like I'm getting close to a desired current output. Thanks you two.